# Cron - crontab executes half of bash script

Tags: bash, cron, curl

I have a bash script named testScript.sh that looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X GET https://www.example.com -o ~/Desktop/testFile.json
curl -X POST -d ~/Desktop/testFile.json http://www.example2.com
```

i want to run this script with crontab so i edited crontab file with `crontab -e` command like that :

```
* * * * * ~/Desktop/testScript.sh
```

The weird part is that when i run the script manually like `./testScript.sh` with pi user, both curl commands execute just fine. When the script runs from crontab i see the testFile created so the first curl command execute, but the curl Post is not executed. I have already did my research and most of the people say it's environment variables but i don't seem to understand any of the answers.

EDIT* I followed @roaima suggestion to make a log file. 
Logs : ....Couldn't read data from file testFile.json", this make an empty Warning : post ....... the curl post then is giving me a 400 bad request because there is not content to post.
1) the testFile.json is created with the first curl command, i see it locally on my machine, i don't know why it cannot read it.
2) the script still runs fine if i run it like that./testScript.sh

Comment: How do you know that the second command is not executed? Could it have run but failed? Modify your `crontab` entry to capture _stdout_ and _stderr_ by appending `>> output.log 2>&1`. Then change your script so the first line reads `#!/bin/bash -x`. Wait one minute and then look in the `output.log` for in your `HOME` directory.

Comment: Are you getting any errors emailed to you by the cron daemon relating to this?

Comment: I have a raspberry pi that it's not mine so i dont know the email @Kusalananda

Comment: log file : "Couldn't read data from file testFile.json", this make an empty Warning : post .......  the curl post then is giving me a 400 bad request because there is not content to post. Two things to point out : 1) the testFile.json is created i don't know why it cannot read it , 2) the script runs fine if i run it like that ./testScript.sh @roaima

Comment: Please add that to your question. You could start by saying that after being prompted by a comment you added the error tracing and discovered these messages.... (It's better for people to be able to see everything in one place.)

Comment: If you want curl to send the *contents* of a file, and not just the filename, you would need `-d @filename` but tilde `~` will not be expanded so use `-d @$HOME/Desktop/testFile.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @meuh that took me 3 hours to figure out. I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem was given out by @meuh

> If you want `curl` to send the contents of a file, and not just the filename, you would need `-d @filename` but tilde `~` will not be expanded so use `-d @$HOME/Desktop/testFile.json`